# How to use a custom TeX font in a matplotlib plot

Tags: python, fonts, matplotlib, tex

I have seen several answers that change the rc params to use a limited number of different fonts for TeX mark up in axis titles etc, but is there a way to use any font on your system? I can do this without TeX mark up, as follows:

```
font_path = 'C:\Windows\Fonts\Arial.ttf'
font_prop = font_manager.FontProperties(fname=font_path, size=14)
```

then

```
plt.title("Misc Graph", fontproperties=font_prop, size=16,
          verticalalignment='bottom')
plt.xlabel("x axis", fontproperties=font_prop)
plt.ylabel("y axis", fontproperties=font_prop)
plt.legend(loc='lower right', prop=font_prop)
```

But if I do `plt.xlabel("$x axis$", fontproperties=font_prop)`, it ignores the font properties I set out.

Comment: You can screw the the latex preamble, but if you do so you are on your own (it is not officially supported).

Comment: @tcaswell What do you mean exactly?

Comment: See http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/usetex.html